# @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED) vs. no @Transactional annotation at all

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

> [Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#NOT_SUPPORTED). Execute non-transactionally, suspend the current transaction if one exists.

Is `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` the same as no `@Transactional` annotation at all in the following example, provided that `m()` is NOT called from another `@Transactional` method:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void m() {
        repo.insert(new B()); //insert() method is annotated with @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)

}
```

Is a new transaction created for the `insert()` method? When should `Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED` be used?

Answer (score 3):

1. Is `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` the same as no `@Transactional`?

   **No**, When we call m() from a method which have already started a transaction then it first suspends the current transaction and then do its work then after returning is resumes the suspended transaction. While in case of no @Transaction it will not suspend on-going transaction.
   check out following logs:

   o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.getTransaction -  [  ] `Creating new transaction with name` []
    o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl.begin -  [  ] `begin`
    .
    .
    o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.handleExistingTransaction -  [  ] `Suspending current transaction`
    .
    .
    .
    o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.cleanupAfterCompletion -  [  ] `Resuming suspended transaction after completion of inner transaction`
2. Is a new transaction created for the insert() method?

   Yes, new transaction will begin for insert method.

   o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl.begin -  `[  ] begin`
   [  ] `Initiating transaction commit`
   [  ] `committing`

**Note**: Suspended transaction was resumed after insert() transaction was committed.

3.When should Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED be used?

Not quite sure, you want the code to be run non-transactionally. If somehow you enter this code from context where transaction is, you suspend this transaction and continue non-transactionally.

Comment: does it work in autocommit mode when it first suspends the current transaction? Let's say there were more insert() or update() methods without @Transactional annotation.

Comment: when first transaction starts it SET autocommit=1. when we don't demarcate Transaction at application level, by default all database calls run in a transaction.

Comment: Not all, I have @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em, so only the annotated methods are in transaction in my app.

Comment: I am talking about database transaction. set general_log and general_log_file on your mysql server then tail the log file and experiment with @Transactional annotation. Application level transaction and Database transaction are different. [check this article]https://dzone.com/articles/spring-transaction-management-an-unconventional-gu